# No mouse clicks registered in the bottom left area of the screen

Tags: windows-10, mouse, start-menu

Mouse has stopped working in the bottom left area of the screen for me today. I cannot click on the Start menu, I can activate it using keyboard only. When the Start menu is open, the only thing I can do with using a mouse it is to resize, otherwise it reacts to keyboard only.

Other applications (including Windows desktop) are not reacting to any mouse input in the area the Start menu is covering, even when the start menu is closed. This is pretty annoying.

Based on the Windows updates history no updates seem to be installed within last 10 days, however I did not see the issue yesterday, it has started today.

Is this a known issue? Is there any fix or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a fix, only a workaround - I have installed a Start menu replacement utility and the problem is gone.